# Can't get php error handling to work

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 16){
    $usernameerror = "Username is too long (has to be between 6-16 characters";
}

if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 6){
    $usernameerror = "Username is too short (has to be between 6-16 characters";
}

if($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2'])
    $passworderror="the passwords are not the same";

$regex_email = "/^[A-Z a-z 0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z a-z 0-9.-]+\.[A-Z a-z]{2,4}/m";
$regex_firstname = "/^[A-Za-z\-]+$/m";
$regex_lastname = "/^[A-Za-z\-]+$/m";
$regex_postcode =  "^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$";
if(!preg_match($regex_email, $_POST['email'])) {
    $emailerror= "Your email format is wrong, please check this again";
}

if(!preg_match($regex_firstname, $_POST['First_Name'])) {
    $firstnameerror= "Your first name is invalid please try again";
}

if(!preg_match($regex_lastname, $_POST['Last_Name'])) {
    $lastnameerror= "Your first name is invalid please try again";
}

if(strlen($_POST['Address_Line_1']) > 60) {
    $addressline1error = "Address Line 1 is too long (maximum of 60 characters)";
}

if(strlen($_POST['Address_Line_2']) > 60) {
    $addressline2error = "Address Line 2 is too long (maximum of 60 characters)";
}

if(!preg_match($regex_postocde, $_POST['POSTCODE'])) {
    $postcodeerror = "Your Postcode does not have the right format please try again";
}
?>
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="register" action="registration.php" method="post">
    <table width="510" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><p><strong>Registration Form</strong></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" /></td> <?php echo '$usernameerror'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password1" /></td> <?php echo '$passworderror'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password2" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td> <?php echo '$emailerror'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" /></td> <?php echo '$firstnameerror'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" /></td> <?php echo '$lastnameerror'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address Line 1:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Address_Line_1" id="Address_Line_1" /></td> <?php echo '$addressline1error'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address Line 2:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Address_Line_2" id="Address_Line_2" /></td> <?php echo '$addressline2error'; ?> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>County:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="County" id="County" /></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Postcode:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="POSTCODE" id="POSTCODE" /></td> <?php echo '$postcodeerror'; ?> 
        </tr>






        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(empty($usernameerror && $passworderror && $emailerror && $firstnameerror && $lastnameerror && $addressline1error && $addressline2error && $postcodeerror)) {


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
$Address_Line_1 = $_POST['Address_Line_1'];
$Address_Line_2 = $_POST['Address_Line_2'];
$County = $_POST['County'];
$POSTCODE = $_POST['POSTCODE'];


    $hash = hash('sha256', $password1);

function createSalt()
{
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($text, 0, 3);
}+

$salt = createSalt();
$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('comp4', $conn);

//sanitize username
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "INSERT INTO member ( username, password, email, salt, First_Name, Last_Name, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, County, POSTCODE)
        VALUES ( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt', '$First_Name', '$Last_Name', '$Address_Line_1', '$Address_Line_2', '$County', '$POSTCODE');";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

header('Location: index.php');
} else {
header('Location: registration.html');} 
?>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Please register your email!");
}
</script>

<?php
mail($email,'Thank you for registering','Please feel free to browse our store ','From: v1p3r.bc@googlemail.com');
?>
```

This is my registration form right now, and I'm trying to get my code to handle any possible errors when the user submits the form. I've been working at this for hours searching the internet and still it doesn't seem to be working, if anyone could help me spot what's wrong or maybe it's something obvious I can't see. So far ive tried to change up the order, so have the form then validation instead of the other way around, tried to use different if's but nothings worked

Thanks in advance for any help, sorry if this the wrong kind of question to be posting :)

Comment: *How* does it not work?

Comment: just glancing over your code. I see a `+` sign at the end of your `createSalt()` function.  That should not be there

Comment: You have 2 header() functions, but none of them will fire off, because there is html output before. Move php code before html and don't echo anything before header. Even one space before php opening tag will cause error. Turn on error reporting to see what happens.

Comment: Error handling is the least of your worries, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. In addition to that, you are wide open to injection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors and things I would do differently that I spotted right away.

1) I would do a if statement at the beginning of your validation code to see if the form has been submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['/*submit button name*/'])){
/* validation block */
```

}

2) Your $regex_postcode check has a spelling error in it (postocde):

```
if(!preg_match($regex_postocde, $_POST['POSTCODE'])) {
```

3) Your echo statements in the form have single quotes around them so they will be interpreted literally. Instead don't put any quotes there:

```
<td><input type="password" name="password1" /></td> <?php echo $passworderror; ?></tr>
```

Also along with that you need to put a check on it or else it will just echo the error no matter what:

```
if(isset($usernameerror)){echo $usernameerror;} ?>
```

I have not worked through all the code yet, but that this is what I saw at first glance.

Comment: Thank you, I have made those corrections, and i'm continuing to work on it :)